# Create dynamic href inside table cell

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table, href

My problem is this:

I am trying to create some cells in a table, which will be filled by data that I extract from an XML document, but I also want those cells to be hyperlinks. I am doing this:

```
var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('table');
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').text(x.item(i).getAttribute("id")).attr('href', 'www.my-url.com/'+x.item(i).getAttribute("id"));
    table.append(row);
}
```

The cells are filled correctly with the text that I want, but the cells are not clickable. I do not get any errors in the console. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you show us what `x` is and some markup?

Comment: From what you've posted I'd suggest that you're not appending an `a` element into the cells? But that's a guess, based on almost-no information.

Comment: You can't set an href attribute on a `<tr>` tag and expect it to work like a link.  You have to put an `<a href=xxx></a>` tag inside the `<tr>` if you want it to work like a link.

Comment: @SiGanteng x=myvar.getElementsByTagName('service'); just a simple xml manipulation. this works fine because the text in the cells is displayed correctly.

Comment: @jfriend00 how can i add the 'a' element without messing up what i have made here? whenever i try to add it in some way, it stops displaying the items.

Comment: @tk66 - I added an answer below that shows how to put an `<a>` link in the row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set an href attribute on a `<tr>` tag and expect it to work like an `<a>` tag.   Instead, you need to put an `<a>` tag inside the `<tr>` tag.  You can do that like this:

```
var table = $('<table class="mytable"></table>');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var txt = x.item(i).id;
    var url = 'http://www.my-url.com/' + txt;
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').html('<a href="' + url + '">' + txt + '</a>');
    table.append(row);
}
```

That method creates the HTML and lets the browser parse it.  You could also create the elements directly like this:

```
var table = $('<table class="mytable"></table>');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var txt = x.item(i).id;
    var url = 'http://www.my-url.com/' + txt;
    var row = $('<tr></tr>')
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.innerHTML = txt;
    row.append(link);
    table.append(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`var row = $('<tr></tr>').html(....`